# Google maps street view panorama options

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm utilizing the `Street View` option with `Google Maps` but I can't figure out how to customize the controls if don't have the street view as the initial screen. Right now I have:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        zoom: 14,
        streetViewControl: true,
        streetViewControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
        },
        zoomControl:false,
        disableDefaultUI: false
```

so this will enable the Pegman that you can drag to switch to the street view but I want to disable the close box and the zoom. I did find [this API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-controls) but I'm not sure how to set the controls when I'm not manually creating the street view myself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Directly after you create your map object, you can do:

```
  map.get('streetView')
  .setOptions({
               addressControlOptions: { 
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
               },
               zoomControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
               },
               panControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
               },
            })
```

Or, however else you'd like to setup your controls.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions
is a list of available options.  You can also pass a new StreetViewPanorama upon creating your map object, but unless you have some serious customization to do, it's not necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the full screen control in street view? `fullscreenControl: false` only removes the control for the overall map

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of the map object. When the event is called, run the following: `map.set('zoomControl', false)`

`map.set('enableCloseButton', false)`

Comment: I feel like that would just set those values to the map and not the street view. I already set `zoomControl: false` in the options when I create the map